# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} <\frac{33}{20}$ using elementary inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

There are many ingenious ways for proving $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} \approx 1.6449$$

Using the inequality $$\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}} =\frac{1}{n-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$ we can see that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} <\frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow \zeta(2)<\frac{5}{3}=1.6666$$

Can we improve upon these bounds using elementary inequalities? Like is it possible to show (of course without assuming $\zeta(2)\approx 1.64449$) that $\zeta(2)<\frac{33}{20}$?

If there are much nicer bounds which follow using elementary inequalities I would be happy to see them.

Comment: If you applied the same thing for the remainder term of higher partial sums, eventually you should get an upper bound arbitrarily close to $\zeta(2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need a few more terms:
$$\zeta(2)<1+\frac14+\frac19+\sum_{n=4}^\infty\frac1{n^2-1/4}
=1+\frac14+\frac19+\frac27$$
which is already less than $33/20$.

Answer (score 3):

Beuker-like integrals are really helpful. We have $\zeta(2)=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log x}{1+x}\,dx $ and 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(x)x^4(1-x)^2}{1+x}\,dx= -\frac{493}{150}+2\,\zeta(2). $$
The LHS is positive and bounded by $\frac{1}{120}$, hence
$$ \zeta(2) \in\left(\frac{493}{300},\frac{659}{400}\right)$$
implies $\zeta(2)=\color{green}{1.64}\ldots$

---

By creative telescoping™, the inequality $x\leq \text{arctanh}(x)$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and the Weierstrass product for the (hyperbolic)sine function we also have
$$ \zeta(2) \leq \frac{205}{144}+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{36\sinh\pi}{85\pi}\right) $$
implying $\zeta(2)<1.645=\frac{329}{200}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way
to get good
bounds for 
the tail of the sum.

I will show that
$\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{x^2}
=\dfrac1{m}+\dfrac1{2(m-1)m}
-\dfrac1{3(m-1)m(m+1)}
-\dfrac{c}{(m-1)m(m+1)(m+2)}
$
where
$0 < c < 1$.

This method
can be extended
to higher order 
error terms,
but what I have done
is enough for me.

I am sure that
this was known
to Euler,
but this is
independent.

$\dfrac1{x^2}-\dfrac1{x(x+1)}
=\dfrac{1}{x^2(x+1)}
$
and
$\dfrac{1}{x^2(x+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(x-1)x(x+1)}
=\dfrac{-1}{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}
$
so
$\dfrac1{x^2}
=\dfrac1{x(x+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(x-1)x(x+1)}
-\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}
$.

Let
$p(x, n)
=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{p(x, n)}-\dfrac1{p(x+1, n)}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+1+k)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x+k)}\left(\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac1{x+n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x+k)}
\dfrac{n}{x(x+n)}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n} (x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{p(x, n+1)}
\\
\end{array}\\
$

Therefore
$\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac{n}{p(x, n+1)}
=\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} (\dfrac1{p(x, n)}-\dfrac1{p(x+1, n)})
=\dfrac1{p(m, n)}
$
or
$\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p(x, n+1)}
=\dfrac1{np(m, n)}
$.

We have

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{x^2}
&=\dfrac1{x(x+1)}+\dfrac{1}{(x-1)x(x+1)}
-\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{p(x, 2)}+\dfrac1{p(x-1, 3)}
-\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}\\
\text{so}\\
\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{x^2}
&=\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{p(x, 2)}+\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{p(x-1, 3)}
-\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{p(m, 1)}+\dfrac1{2p(m-1, 2)}
-\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{m}+\dfrac1{2(m-1)m}
-\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

Also

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{p(x-1, 4)}
&=\dfrac1{(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)}\\
&\lt \dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}\\
&\lt \dfrac1{(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)}\\
&=\dfrac1{p(x-2, 4)}\\
\end{array}
$

and
$\dfrac1{p(x-2, 4)}-\dfrac1{p(x-1, 4)}
=\dfrac{4}{p(x-1, 5)}
$
so that
$0
\lt \dfrac1{(x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)}-\dfrac1{p(x-2, 4)}
\lt \dfrac{4}{p(x-1, 5)}
$.

Therefore,
since
$\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p(x-2, 4)}
=\dfrac1{4p(m-2, 3)}
$
and
$\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p(x-1, 5)}
=\dfrac1{5p(m-1, 4)}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}
&\gt \sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p(x-1, 4)}\\
&= \dfrac1{3p(m-1, 3)}\\
&= \dfrac1{3(m-1)m(m+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{x=m}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(x-1)x^2(x+1)}
&\lt \sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p(x-2, 4)}\\
&\lt \sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p(x-1, 4)}+\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac{4}{p(x-1, 5)}\\
&= \dfrac1{3p(m-1, 3)}+\dfrac1{p(m-1, 4)}\\
&= \dfrac1{3(m-1)m(m+1)}+\dfrac1{(m-1)m(m+1)(m+2)}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\sum_{x=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{x^2}
=\dfrac1{m}+\dfrac1{2(m-1)m}
-\dfrac1{3(m-1)m(m+1)}
= -\dfrac{c}{(m-1)m(m+1)(m+2)}
$
where
$0 < c < 1$.